# How to upload files under taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, files

Suppose in a School's website, I have some departments. They want their class lectures, class routines, course curriculum to be uploaded under their departments. Typically we did some very simple things - all the departments are now simple hierarchical pages. How to go with it.

We thought to go with a new content type, where the taxonomy will be the department name, where under the department names will be the type of document (whether class routine, or class lecture etc.) and under that taxonomy if we write a content, then we can go through the taxonomies to the content. In a scene they will be:

```
Home
  - Departments
     - Zoology
       - Class Lecture
         - Content
       - Class Routine
         - Content
       - Class Curriculum
         - Content
     - Biology
       - Class Lecture
         - Content
       - Class Routine
         - Content
       - Class Curriculum
         - Content
```

BUT NOT the file directly. We need to attach file under taxonomy, not the content. So there is a problem.

How can we proceed to such extent?

Comment: Are you using Drupal 7?

Comment: @JayendraKainthola: Yap. 7.15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach `file` with `taxonomy` as below:

- Go to Administration -> Structure -> Taxonomy
- Edit `Vocabulary`, which you want to use, from the list of `Vocabulary`.

  [image]
- Click on "Manage Fields" tab in the top of the page.

  [image]
- Add new field of `field type` as `file` and assign the required `file extension` which you want to upload and save the field.

  [image]

  [image]

  [image]
- When you create new term of the vocabulary, it will allow you to upload file with term.

  [image]